# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^2}{(1 + x^2)^n}$ on $\Bbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

I was trying to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^2}{(1 + x^2)^n}$ converges uniformly on $\Bbb{R}$.

was trying to use $M$ test, in which I am trying to bound $|f_{n}(x)| < M_{n} $ such that $M_{n}$ converges uniformly.

I thought of using $|\frac{(-1)^{n}x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}| < |\frac{(-1)^n x^2}{(1 + nx^2)}| < |\frac{(-1)^n x^2}{nx^2}| < |\frac{(-1)^n}{n}|$ which converges absolutely and hence The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^2}{(1 + x^2)^n}$  converges absolutely for all $x$.

Comment: But $\sum_n 1/n$ doesn't converge...

Comment: You can compute the partial sums explicitly using the formula for sum of geometric series.

Comment: Ok, but i think geometric series would be useful if it was $\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ ?? as $S_{n}(x)$ sems like alternating series

Comment: the point is you can figure out what the series converges to by @KaviRamaMurthy hint, and then show that the error is uniform in $x$

Comment: How about using the ratio test??

Comment: @BAYMAX $\sum_{0}^{\infty} r^{n}=\frac 1 {1-r}$ if $|r|<1%$. This is valid even if $r<0$. Take $r=-1/(1+x^{2})$.

Comment: Another question about the same series: [Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ uniformly converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108983)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can analyze the uniform convergence here **without** finding the sum explicitly.  This is good practice for problems where the sum cannot be obtained in closed form.

The M-test is problematic because the series with absolute values of the terms

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$$

is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$.

However, on an interval like $[a,\infty)$ where $a > 0$ we have uniform convergence by the M-test , since for $n \geqslant 2$,

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\right|= \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} \leqslant \frac{x^2}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^4} \leqslant \frac{2}{n(n-1)a^2},$$

and $\sum_{n \geqslant 2} [n(n-1)]^{-1} = 1$.

Nevertheless, the alternating series is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).
Note that $\sum_{n=1}^m (-1)^{n-1}$ is uniformly bounded for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $x^2/(1+x^2)^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ monotonically and uniformly (as shown by your $1/n$ bound).